# Can I perform a unit test from a .NET application running in the cloud?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am pretty new in **.NET** (I came from Java and Spring framework) and I never worked on the cloud untill now.

At the moment I started to work on a new .NET project deployed in Azure. I know that I can debug it from Visual Studio using the **Cloud Explorer** view but I have a doubt about how can I perform **unit test** in the cloud.

I try to explain better with an example. Into my project I have this controller class:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    /**
     *  Classe controller che implementa le operazioni per protocollare una mail
     */
    public class MailProtocolloController : ApiController
    {

        private String urlBaseProtocolloApi = "http://myserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8081/myApi";

        public void getAooList()
        {
            string jsonRequest = urlBaseProtocolloApi + "/api/myresource/GetDepartmentsList";

            CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
            credCache.Add(new Uri(jsonRequest), "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);

            HttpWebRequest spRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(jsonRequest);
            spRequest.Credentials = credCache;
            spRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.01;+Windows+NT+5.0";
            spRequest.Method = "GET";
            spRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";

            HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)spRequest.GetResponse();
            string sResult;


        }

    }
}
```

Ok, I know that at the moment this API is returning nothing (void), it is still in an embryonic state and I have to change it.

At the moment the only thing that I want to do is to test it using unit test to check if the **sResult** property contains the result.

Questions:

1) To execute my application it have to be deployed in the cloud (because this API call a REST API that have to be on the same environment, infact I am attaching the credentisial using the **CredentialCache** class. Can I deploy this app on the cloud and from here performing my unit test? (something like perform debug in the cloud using the **Cloud Explorer** view.

2) What have I to do to create unit test into a .NET project? (In Java I simply create a class importing JUnit)

Comment: Calling a REST API that is not also hosted inside your unit test is strictly speaking not a unit test. Do you want to mock your dependency or just automate your regular testing and use a unit test project for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) If you have to test it in the cloud, it isn't an unit test, it is an integration test! For integration tests I recommend you postman and the postman runner ([newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman)). You can define your rest calls in postman with an JS scripts to test the responses and you can call the defined test with the CLI-Tool [newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) to automate this.

2.) There are 2 possibilities in C# for Unit Test [MS Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest) and [NUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit). Here is a comparison matrix between the two to decide which matches the best:
http://www.anarsolutions.com/automated-unit-testing-tools-comparison/
If you want somethin similar to JUnit than I think NUint is the best for you:

> NUnit is an open-source unit testing framework for Microsoft .NET. It serves the same purpose as JUnit does in the Java world

For example with MS Test you have to add the MSTest Nuget package, define your class with the annotation `[TestClass]` and your test method with the annotaion `[TestMethod]` afterwards you can use the `Assert` commands in your test method i.e.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void MyTest_Successful()
  {
    Assert.IsTrue(/*Something true*/ true);
  }
}
```